# How to set event for selectionchanged of datagrid combobox?

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid, eventsetter

Hi I have a wpf project which binding datagrid to module like this:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Values">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

This works fine. Now I want to add some features including setting an event the combobox `SelectionChanged`. So I changed the `xaml` file like this:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Values">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    /!-- Add an EventSetter here. -->
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">                                                                                           
                         <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="ValueChanged" />                                                                                  
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox>
              </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

And add an function in the back end like this:

```
    private void ValueChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
         if (comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
         {
              //do something here.
         }
    }
```

But this makes the project breakdown with `error: "The Application is in break mode."` when I changed the combobox cell. So what could be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid as i am. Just setting the event inside the `combobox` fix the problem.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Values">
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                     SelectionChanged="ValueChanged" />
          </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Style` property of the `ComboBox` to your `Style`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ComboBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="ValueChanged" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Style>
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Or you could hook up the event handler directly on the `ComboBox` element and get rid of the `Style`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectionChanged="ValueChanged" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```